# How much resources does a Sharepoint 2010 install use, when not in use?

Tags: performance

The question is a bit off topic, but I have a development machine that is my personal computer too. In other words I use it for a host of other things not just work.

Obviously nothing beats having Sharepoint installed locally if you work with it, this means not having to RDC into a dev server, or having to fire up a virtual server to test out quick things.

Anyways I was wondering, are there any facts as to how much system resources an idle sharepoint 2010 install would use? lets say if it had a max of 1 web app, and 1 site collection. Basically used for dev from time to time, but mostly not being actively used.

The key here is its idle state. Any published stats on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a huge amount. Seems like in my case it was less than 2gb of RAM and I have enough processor so I didn't even worry with CPU. I just was annoyed by the extra startup time for times when I don't need the server fired up.

I set mine to not autostart.  Then I found [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/emberger/stop-and-go-with-sharepoint-2010-on-your-workstation). I got the scripts, but I prefer to use the WPF app that is mentioned in the CodePlex link in the comments.  This can start and stop your SQL Server service jobs too.  I like it a lot.